# my model didn't create a foreign key with seqeulize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, mysql-workbench, backend, sequelize-cli

so i have  create  a  foreign keys for my models ,  entretien  and typeEntretien , the models  are created  in mysql but i cant  find my foreigns  keys , i'm  usign sequelize 6.13.0 , i think  that  the  problem in  the  index   maybe  about object keys ,  i tried  many  solutions  but no one  worked ,  i'm  new  with sequelize , i followed  a  tutto on youtube  , i'm sure that  the  index is wrong

model entretien

````
    module.exports= (sequelize,DataTypes)=>{
        console.log(sequelize);
        const entretien =sequelize.define('entretien',{
            id:{
                type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement:true
            },
           idType:{
                type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
               
            },
            idFournisseur:{
                type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
                
            },
            date:{
                type:DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull:false
            
            },
            montant:{
                type:DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull:false
            }
           
        },
    
        {
            timestamps:true,
            tableName:"entretien",
        }
        
        );
        entretien.associate=function(){
            this.belongsTo(sequelize.models.typeEntretien,{
                foreignKey:'idType'
             
            })
            this.associate=function(){
                this.belongsTo(sequelize.models.fournisseur,{
                    foreignKey:"idFournisseur",
                    as:"fournisseur"
                })
           
        }}
        return entretien
    }
    ```
    
    model typeEntretien 
    ```
    
    module.exports= (sequelize,DataTypes)=>{
        const typeEntretien =sequelize.define('typeEntretien',{
           
           id:{
               type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
               primaryKey:true,
               autoIncrement:true
            },
               
             
               libelle:{
                   type:DataTypes.STRING
               }
      
          },
          {
            timestamps:true,
            tableName:"typeEntretien",
        }
          );
      
          
      
        return typeEntretien
    }
    ```
    
    idex.js  of sequelize 
    const dbConfig=require('../config/dbConfig')
    
    const {Sequelize ,DataTypes}=require('sequelize')
    
    const sequelize =new Sequelize(
        dbConfig.DB,
        dbConfig.USER,
        dbConfig.PASSWORD,{
            host:dbConfig.HOST,
            dialect:dbConfig.dialect,
            operatorAliases:false,
            options: {
                requestTimeout: 60000,
              },
            
            pol:{
                max:dbConfig.pool.max,
                min:dbConfig.pool.min,
                acquire:dbConfig.pool.acquire,
                idle:dbConfig.pool.idle
            }
        }
    
    )
    
    sequelize.authenticate()
    .then(()=>{
        console.log('connected..');
    })
    .catch(err=>{
    console.log('Error' +err);
    })
    
    const db={}
    
    db.Sequelize=Sequelize
    db.sequelize=sequelize
    
    
    Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
        console.log(db);
        if (db[modelName].associate) {
          db[modelName].associate(db);
        }
      });
    
    
    db.users=require('./user.js')(sequelize , DataTypes)
    db.conducteur=require('./conducteur.js')(sequelize , DataTypes)
    db.voiture=require('./voiture.js')(sequelize , DataTypes)
    db.entretien=require('./entretien.js')(sequelize , DataTypes)
    db.fournisseur=require('./fournisseur')(sequelize , DataTypes)
    db.réparation=require('./réparation')(sequelize , DataTypes)
    db.transport=require('./transport')(sequelize , DataTypes)
    db.typeEntretien=require('./typeEntretien')(sequelize , DataTypes)
    db.marqueVoiture=require('./marqueVoiture')(sequelize , DataTypes)
    
    
    
    
    db.sequelize.sync({force :true})
    .then(()=>{
        console.log('yes re-sync done');
    })
    
    module.exports=db
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to correct `associate` function like this:

```js
entretien.associate=function(){
            entretien.belongsTo(sequelize.models.typeEntretien,{
                foreignKey:'idType'
             
            })
            entretien.belongsTo(sequelize.models.fournisseur,{
                    foreignKey:"idFournisseur",
                    as:"fournisseur"
            })
}
```

Second, you need to move associations registration after this line:

```js
 db.marqueVoiture=require('./marqueVoiture')(sequelize , DataTypes)
 // all models should be registered and stored in db object prior this code
 Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
        console.log(db);
        if (db[modelName].associate) {
          db[modelName].associate(db);
        }
      });
```